# I'm using "sails": "~1.2.4". I'm trying to connect to a MongoDb. But When I try to sails lift I get this error:

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails-mongo

````
**Error Type**
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
    at Object.teardown (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\index.js:390:19)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:758:27
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3047:20
    at eachOfArrayLike (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1002:13)
    at eachOf (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1052:9)
    at Object.eachLimit (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3111:7)
    at Object.teardown (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:742:11)
    at Hook.teardown (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\index.js:246:30)
    at Sails.wrapper (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3282:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Sails.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\after.js:56:26)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:67:11
    at beforeShutdown (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:45:12)
    at Sails.lower (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lower.js:49:3)
    at Sails.wrapper [as lower] (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3282:19)
    at whenSailsIsReady (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lift.js:68:13)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3861:9
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:421:16
    at iterateeCallback (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:924:17)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:906:16
error: 
error: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager:
```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  name: 'MongoError'
}]
    at flaverr (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\flaverr\index.js:94:15)
    at Function.module.exports.parseError (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\flaverr\index.js:371:12)
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:665:56)
    at connectCb (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\private\machines\create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:335:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```
    at Object.error (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\index.js:268:21)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:1514:39
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:1153:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:845:10)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\parley\lib\private\Deferred.js:303:7
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\machine\lib\private\help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at connectCb (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\sails-mongo\lib\private\machines\create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at D:\HTML\Sails\test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:335:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

error: Could not load Sails app.
error: 
error: Tips:
error:  • First, take a look at the error message above.
error:  • Make sure you've installed dependencies with `npm install`.
error:  • Check that this app was built for a compatible version of Sails.
error:  • Have a question or need help?  (http://sailsjs.com/support)
````

**/config/datastores.js**

```
    module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: "sails-mongo",
    url: "mongodb://root@localhost/datab",
  },
};
```

**config/models.js**

```
module.exports.models = {

  schema: true,

  migrate: "alter",

  attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: "number", autoCreatedAt: true },
    updatedAt: { type: "number", autoUpdatedAt: true },
    id: { type: "string", columnName: "_id" },
    deleted: { type: "boolean", defaultsTo: false },
  },

  dataEncryptionKeys: {
    default: "t9AkMiCRfZeODiZKQsgGif2zsE40wKJK6Uudr51L4hU=",
  },

  cascadeOnDestroy: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: require("sails-mongo"),
    url: "mongodb://root@localhost/datab",
  },
};
```